# java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, исключения, scanner

Помогите разобраться, я новичок. Ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>           at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
>           at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
>           at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
>           at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
>           at kalkulator.main(kalkulator.java:36)
>       "

Вот код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class kalkulator {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        Scanner vod = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cheslo1,cheslo2,rezultat;
        String diya;

        System.out.println("Введіть перше число:");
        cheslo1 = (vod.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Введіть друге число:");
        cheslo2 =(vod.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Виберіть дію +-/*");
        diya =vod.nextLine();
        if(diya.equals("+"))
        {
            rezultat =cheslo1+cheslo2;
        }
        else if(diya.equals("-"))
        {
            rezultat=cheslo1-cheslo2;   
        }
        else if(diya.equals("/"))
        {
            rezultat=cheslo1*cheslo2;
        }
        else if(diya.equals("*"))
        {
            rezultat=cheslo1+cheslo2;
        }

        cheslo2 = (vod.nextInt());
        rezultat=cheslo1 + cheslo2;
        System.out.print("Результат:");
        System.out.print(rezultat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Название переменных лучше писать на английском языке numberOne numberTwo и т д

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 0):

В общем ниже переделанный вариант с измененными названиями переменных не генерирует исключения:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double val, val1, result;
    String symbol;

    try(Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in)){
        System.out.println("Введите первое число: ");
        val = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Введите второе число: ");
        val1 = scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Введите знак: ");
        symbol= scan.next();
    }


    switch (symbol){
        case "/" : result = val / val1;
        break;

        case "*" : result = val * val1;
        break;

        case "+" : result = val + val1;
        break;

        case "-" : result = val - val1;
        break;

        default: result = -1;
        break;
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Ошибка могла произойти из-за того, что:

- Вы не закрываете поток `vod` .
- Вы неправильно используете `nextLine()`.
- Зачем вы второй раз присваиваете значение переменной `cheslo2`?

Comment: А зачем вам нужен оператор try в этой программе? С nextLine() согласен.

Comment: Класс Scanner является потоком сканирующий входящие в него данные и его нужно явно нужно закрыть методом close(). Но для удобства он реализует интерфейс AutoCloseable и для него можно использовать try с ресурсами. Это позволяет неявно вызывать метод close() т.е. закрыть поток.

Comment: Ясно. Просто здесь и без этого можно обойтись, исправив метод.

Comment: Конечно можно. Но нужно избежать утечки данных (даже в таких малых проектах), а для этого лучше воспользоваться try с ресурсами.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class kalkulator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner vod = new Scanner(System.in);
        double cheslo1, cheslo2, rezultat = 0;
        String diya;

        System.out.println("Введіть перше число:");
        cheslo1 = (vod.nextDouble());

        System.out.println("Введіть друге число:");
        cheslo2 = (vod.nextDouble());

        System.out.println("Виберіть дію +-/*");
        // diya =vod.nextLine(); 
        diya = vod.next(); 

        if (diya.equals("+")) {
            rezultat = cheslo1 + cheslo2;
        } else if (diya.equals("-")) {
            rezultat = cheslo1 - cheslo2;
        } else if (diya.equals("/")) {
            rezultat = cheslo1 / cheslo2;
        } else if (diya.equals("*")) {
            rezultat = cheslo1 * cheslo2;
        }
        //cheslo2 = (vod.nextInt());
        // rezultat=cheslo1 + cheslo2;
        System.out.print("Результат:" + rezultat);
    }
}
```

Для чтения строки из потока ввода применяются методы `next()` или `nextLine()`.

[Используемые методы сканера](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/rabota-so-skannerom-v-java/):

`next ();` - считывает введённую строку до первого пробела

`nextLine ();` - считывает всю введённую строку

`nextInt ();` - считывает введённое число int

`nextDouble ();` - считывает введённое число double